# Tooltip not showing in Altair plots

Tags: python, altair

Tootip not showing up and and getting an error message

data set

[image]

coding
lcp = alt.Chart(lc).mark_bar().encode(alt.X('Plant ID'),
alt.Y('perimeter cm', tooltip=['Plant ID']))
lcp

try to include tooltip "Plant ID" and I got

SchemaValidationError: Invalid specification

```
    altair.vegalite.v4.schema.channels.Y, validating 'additionalProperties'

    Additional properties are not allowed ('tooltip' was unexpected)
```

alt.Chart(...)

Answer (score 1):

That error implies that tooltip is not an argument you can pass to alt.Y

Instead, place it outside of alt.Y and inside encoding like so:

```
lcp = alt.Chart(lc).mark_bar().encode(alt.X('Plant ID'),
    alt.Y('perimeter cm'), tooltip=['Plant ID']))
```

Passing the keyword argument tooltip is the same as instantiating the tooltip positional argument, like you do with alt.X or alt.Y above, and giving it a field like with the cars dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
import vega_datasets 
cars = vega_datasets.data.cars()
lcp = alt.Chart(cars).mark_bar().encode(alt.X('Miles_per_Gallon'),
                                      alt.Y('Horsepower'), alt.Tooltip(["Name"]))
```

See [the docs](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/channels/altair.Tooltip.html?highlight=tooltip) for more info on tooltips.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).